# Photoshop CC (for retina display) fonts blurry when exported to jpg or pdf

Tags: adobe-photoshop, fonts, typography, export, cc-2014

I have a retina display mac, and I'm using Photoshop CC, which is really crisp when I'm working on a PSD file.
But once I export the file to a PDF or a JPG, the image stays crisp but the fonts (not all of them) go blurry.
Could someone please explain the way around this?
Is it the font which needs reinstalling? (I don't think so as some of the text using the same font is blurred and other crisp)
or is there a special setting I need to use?

Thank you for your help, I can't work without this solution!

Janna

Comment: Let me know if you want a photo

Comment: what are your settings?

Comment: Does it behave the same on non retina displays - e.g. crisp in PS, blurry when exported?

Comment: Hi, thanks for your replies. So I can't compare for now with non retina cause I only have one computer ;). About my settings do you mean export settings? The jpg I tried export for web, but also regular jpg export (quality 8, with different settings : basic, basic optimized). For the PDF I choose the best quality preset. For the font settings I also tried different things (Precise, mac etc).

Comment: Anyone? Could someone please give me a solution? Thank you.

Comment: Could you attach photo/explain settings? Sounds like an anti-aliasing problem to me.

Answer (score 1):

To change the way your fonts look and prevent that blurry effect, maybe you could make some tests changing the font anti-aliasing setting on the character panel (see screenshot below.) You need to select the same one for each line of texts.

I think what you may be looking for is the Mac LCD option for your font.

=====

EDIT: One thing I also noticed:

You should be careful to use "full value" for your font size and line-height. For example, if you use a font at 11.86pts, it might looks a bit blurry. You should round the number to 12pts or 11pts.

[image: Mac LCD font and character for Retina display]

=====

**For PDF or export JPG/PNG:**

It's also possible to convert your text layers to vector using Illustrator, and then exporting your PDF and JPG with Illustrator. Your texts will be sharper:

[How to keep the text in vector in Photoshop without rasterizing it or flattening the layers when exporting to PDF?](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/55345/how-to-keep-the-text-in-vector-in-photoshop-without-rasterizing-it-or-flattening)

Answer (score -1):

There are also the 'crisp' 'normal' and other text modes near the font size option.

Comment: Ok. Why is this. I see lots of anwsers in various questions that don't explain themselfs.

Comment: Hi DatScreamer, welcome to GD.SE. This is an automated message, posted because your answer is below a certain length. One-line answers *can* be good, but more often they benefit from some clarification. Personally, I'd prefer you to add some more clarification, because I can't really see how this answers the question and helps the asker. Thanks! If you have any questions about the site, have a look at the [help] or ping one of us in [chat] once your reputation reaches 20.